# Can Installshield Express create patches (.msp)?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, patch, msp

Can you create a Windows Installer Patch (.msp) with Installshield Express?

Answer (score 0):

Per [FlexeraSoftware](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield/features.htm), patch creation is not a feature of InstallShield Express.